# How can I prevent Quasar dropdown list from scrolling with the page?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, quasar-framework

I have following Code, using Quasar (Vue 3.0) and have following code:

```
      <q-select filled v-model="model" :options="options" label="Filled" />
```

But when the Drop Down is open and then scroll the page, Popup List Scroll with page. How I can prevent to scroll the pop-up list with page? I means after opening the list of drop down, that list bind to drop down and not scroll with form.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBPew.png)

in the above picture we scroll the form and drop down items move with page !!!!

Comment: It's not possible to change.  The reason it scrolls with the page is because the menu sub-component is attached to the root node of the app, and not the select component itself (using [teleport](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/teleport.html) to do so).  Quasar does not offer anything in the way of props to change this behavior for QSelect.

Comment: What I mean is that the Quasar component uses teleport internally.  You can't change this fact without changing the Quasar source code (which is beyond my skill level to help with).  This is the way the developers of Quasar wanted it to be.  Not everything in a framework is customizable, this being one of them.  If this behavior is a deal breaker for your app, you'll need to use a different library or make your own custom select.

Answer (score 0):

You can from intersection observer
Use it and close the pop-up as soon as you pass the drop down

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think saeed meant this solution: to close the popup to avoid the scrolling issue:

```
<template>
    <q-select ref="selectRef" v-intersection="hidePopup" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
    const selectRef = ref<QSelect | null>(null);

    function hidePopup() {
        selectRef.value?.hidePopup();
    }
</script>
```

Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem entirely for me.